# Fractional part of rational power arbitrary small

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation, fractional-part

I think that $\{a^n\}$ (where $\{x\}$ is $x \pmod 1$), where $a$ is fixed rational greater than 1 and $n$ is positive integer, is dense in $[0,1]$ is unsolved. However what about $\{a^n\}$ is arbitrary small for some $n$ ($a$ is fixed rational as well).

Comment: If ${a^n}$ is shown to take on arbitrarily small values, for every possible rational (nonintegral) $a>1$, then that would mean that $0$ had been shown to be a limit point of the fractional parts of all the possible choices of base $a$ for the powers $a^n$. If this were known it likely would have appeared on the Wolfram page http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerFractionalParts.html but I didn't see it there. The subject seems complex in general.

Comment: seems like you are saying that n is fixed as we vary a. i will try and rephrase the problem

Comment: Actually I see that it means for a fixed $a$ one computes the fractional parts of $a,a^2,a^3,\cdots$ and checks whether that sequence has $0$ as a limit point. This idea of limit points of these sequences (for fixed $a$) is what is discussed on the Wolfram page I linked in my previous comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that the [wolfram link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerFractionalParts.html) cited the first result ([Vijayaraghavan 1941](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100017989)) **incorrectly** where it reports that

> $\{ (3/2)^n \}$ has infinitely many accumulation points in both $[0, 1/2)$ and $[1/2, 1]$.

The first result actually is

> $\{ (3/2)^n \}$ has infinitely many accumulation points in $[0,1]$.

The second result cited by wolfram is by Flatto, Lagarias, Pollington (1995) which is available here: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa70/aa7023.pdf. In the introduction of this paper by them, it reports that

> Vijayaraghavan later remarked that it was striking that
>   one could not even decide whether or not $(3/2)^n$ mod $1$ has infinitely
>   many limit points in $[0, 1/2)$ or in $[1/2, 1)$.

This paper proved that

> $$\limsup\{ (3/2)^n \} - \liminf \{(3/2)^n\} \geq \frac13. $$

A few later results are mentioned (Dubickas [2006](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/mana.200510651), [2008](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2005.07.004)) in Yann Bugeaud's book "Distribution Modulo One and Diophantine Approximation" (for example, [p. xi](https://books.google.com/books?id=NeEpoAf7k0IC&pg=PR11), [p. 67](https://books.google.com/books?id=NeEpoAf7k0IC&pg=PA67) and [p. 68](https://books.google.com/books?id=NeEpoAf7k0IC&pg=PA68)).

> $\{ (3/2)^n \}$ has a limit point in $[0.238117 . . . , 0.761882 . . .]$ which has length $0.523764 . . .$.
>
> $\{(3/2)^n\}$ has a limit point in $[0, 8/39] \cup
> [18/39, 21/39] \cup [31/39, 1]$, of total length $19/39$.

Comment: @MartinSleziak, Thank you very much for putting the links to the papers and the book, also for the bounty.

Comment: Though accepted and rewarded, this answer does not adress the question, which was: "what about $\{a^n\}$ is arbitrary small for some $n$?"

Answer (score 4):

I will show that
if $a = 1+\sqrt{2}$
then the limit points of
$\{a^n\}$
are $0$ and $1$.

I know that this doesn't tell anything
about rational $a$,
but this might be of use.

Note that this method can show this
for $a$ and $b$ roots of
$x^2-2ux-v = 0$
where $u$ and $v$ are
positive integers such that
$v < 2u+1$.
This case is $u=v=1$;
$u=1, v=2$ also works.

If $a = \sqrt{2}+1$
and
$b = 1-\sqrt{2}$
then
$ab = -1$
and
$a+b = 2$.

Therefore $a$ and $b$
are the roots of
$x^2-2x-1 = 0$.

If $u_n = a^n+b^n$,
then
$u_0 = 2,
u_1 = 2$.

Since
$a^{n+2}
=a^n(a^2)
=a^n(2a+1)
=2a^{n+1}+a^n$
and similarly for $b$,

$\begin{array}\\
u_{n+2}
&=a^{n+2}+b^{n+2}\\
&=2a^{n+1}+a^n+2b^{n+1}+b^n\\
&=2u_{n+1}+u_n\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$u_n$ is a
positive integer for all $n$.

Since
$|b| < 1$,
$|b^n| \to 0$.

Since
$b < 0$,
$b^{2n} > 0$
and
$b^{2n+1} < 0$.

Therefore,
since
$a^n = u_n - b^n$,
$\{a^{2n}\}
=\{u_{2n}-b^{2n}\}
=1-b^{2n}
$
so
$\{a^{2n}\}
\to 1
$
and
$\{a^{2n+1}\}
=\{u_{2n+1}-b^{2n+1}\}
=\{u_{2n+1}+|b^{2n+1}\}
=|b^{2n+1}|
$
so
$\{a^{2n+1}\}
\to 0
$.

Therefore
the limits points of
$\{a^n\}$
are $0$ and $1$.

Comment: But does the problem not ask for rational $a$? Quadratic surds are a much easier case.

Comment: I mentioned that in my answer.

Comment: @Oscar :One should say *"this answer is really a comment, but too long for a comment-box"*. But I find it useful to see one way of reasoning, even if the variable *a* is irrational here, how one could possibly approach such a question.

Answer (score -1):

Edit: sorry, I now realize that the question asks whether 0 is a limit point of $\{a^n\}$. My answer below is not a paraphrase of the question but is something weaker. But I still hope it helps.

---

Let me rephrase the question:
Let $a$ be a rational greater than 1, is it true that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\{a^n\} = 0$?

When $a$ is an integer, yes, $\lim_{n \to \infty}\{a^n\} = \lim_{n \to \infty} 0 = 0$.

However, When $a$ is a noninteger rational, $\lim_{n \to \infty}\{a^n\} \ne 0$.

Proof by contradiction, assume $\lim_{n \to \infty}\{a^n\} = 0$. let $$ be the denominator of $\{a\}$, we can find an $$ such that $∀ n > $, $\{x^n\} < \frac{1}{aq}$.

Let $ > $, we have

$$\{a^m\} < \frac{1}{aq} \tag{1}\label{1}$$ and

$$\{a^{m+1}\} < \frac{1}{aq} < \frac{1}{q} \tag{2}\label{2} $$
where

\begin{align}
\{a^{m+1}\} &=  \{ (⌊a^m⌋ + \{a^m\}) (⌊a⌋ + \{a\}) \} \\  & = \{ ⌊a^m⌋⌊a⌋ + ⌊a^m⌋\{a\} +  \{a^m\}(⌊a⌋ + \{a\}) \} \\  
&= \{⌊a^m⌋\{a\} +  \{a^m\}(⌊a⌋ + \{a\})\} \\
&= \{⌊a^m⌋\{a\} +  \{a^m\}a\} \\
& = \{\{⌊a^m⌋\{a\}\} +  \{a^m\}a\}
\end{align}

where the last step comes from the observation that { + } = {{} + }.

Note $\{⌊a^m⌋\{a\}\}$ is one of $1/, 2/, 3/... (-1) / $, in particular

$$ \frac{1}{q} \le \{⌊a^m⌋\{a\}\} \le \frac{q-1}{q}  \tag{3}\label{3}$$

We have $1/ < \{⌊a^m⌋\{a\}\} +  \{a^m\}a < 1$ by \eqref{1} \eqref{3}, which implies $\{a^{m+1}\} = \{\{⌊a^m⌋\{a\}\} +  \{a^m\}a\} > 1/$ which contradicts \eqref{2}.