# Is the decimal part of $\exp (\pi \sqrt{n})$ dense on the interval $(0,1)$?

Tags: analysis

We know that Ramanujan's constant $e^{\pi \sqrt{163}}$ is very close to an integer([see wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_integer#Almost_integers_relating_to_e_and_%CF%80)), and there is no closer to an integer than $163$ when $n$ is less than $1$ million.

Can we prove such a strengthened proposition:

> the decimal part of $l_n = e^{\pi \sqrt{n}}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ is dense on $(0, 1)$.

In this way, $l_n$ can approach $\alpha\in (0, 1)$, so we can know that $l_{163}$ is not the one closest to integers.

Comment: I suspect this is a hard problem. The question of the density of the decimal part of $x^n$ (where $x > 1$ is not an integer) is [already tricky](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453673/fractional-part-of-rational-power-arbitrary-small/), even in the case $x = 3/2$. It's possible that the $x^{\sqrt{n}}$ variant is easier somehow, but I'd be surprised.

Comment: Even if $e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}$ is not the closest to an integer, if the fractional parts are (e.g.) "uniformly distributed" in $(0,1)$ then $l_{163}$ can be much closer than we would have expected from a sample size of $163$.

Comment: Some interesting comments can be found in [A069014](http://oeis.org/A069014).

Comment: It is certainly true, but how to prove it?

Comment: For all $a\in[0,1]$ one has $\pi\sqrt x=a$ with $x=\dfrac{a^2}{\pi^2}$, so we can deduce that the fractional part $\pi\sqrt x-\lfloor{\pi\sqrt x}\rfloor$ is dense in $[0,1]$. Thus the set of fractional parts of the exponents of $e$ is dense in $[0,1]$.From this, I think someone can deduce the asked result.

Comment: I wonder if it would help to concentrate on subsequences with $n=m^2$, $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then we look on $e^{m\pi}\ mod\ 1$, which seems at least a bit simpler...

Comment: Related post on MathOverflow:  [Why are powers of $\exp(\pi\sqrt{163})$ almost integers?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/4775/430031)